# Too large batch size or timeout while waiting for server response while exporting data into cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to import data from CSV files to cassandra using cassandra-loader:
https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

**Cassandra-version: 3.1**

Export data from cassandra into CSV files takes ~ 20 minutes which is ok.
Import data using this command: 
cassandra-loader -f "path to files" -host "host" -schema "scema" -numThreads 40 takes more than 7 hours.
If i try to increase -batchSize over than ~1.5k and -rate over than 50k than i get an error.

```
Error inserting: Batch too large
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large
```

Sometimes i get error like "Server responce timeout"

```
Timed out waiting for server response
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [] Timed out waiting for server response
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onTimeout(RequestHandler.java:772)
```

How can i fix it and speed it up?

Or maybe there is another way to import fast data from CSV into cassandra

Comment: Try using `COPY` command...

Comment: COPY command can't help me because it can copy approximately 2 million rows only. I need to copy more than 1 billion